# functions dont work in loaded content ajax .delegate, on Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates

I have some results that are loaded via `Ajax` in the  `#results` container and anothers, the same content in `#last_results` (this one loads without ajax). The same scripts that work on `#last_results` doesnt work in `#results` I think due to they are not binded.

**HTML**

```
 <ul id="results"></ul>

     <ul id="last_results">
                    <li class=showLb>[click to show LightBox]</li>
                    <li class=showLb>[click to show LightBox]</li>
                    <li class=showLb>[click to show LightBox]</li>
    </ul>
```

**JQUERY** This is a basic Jquery script:

```
   $('.showLb').on('click',function(e){
           alert('Show LightBox');

       });
```

This script works in the page `li` but not in the loaded via Ajax `li`. I knew I have to `delegate` or use `on`, How

Comment: look for jQuery delegate

Comment: I am, but I cant find the way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Now, My preference would be to ask you to actually go and check what this change does. Remember, we are here to help you understand.

```js
$('.results').on('click', '.showLb' ,function(e){
        alert('Show LightBox');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="results"></ul>

     <ul id="last_results">
                    <li class=showLb>[click to show LightBox]</li>
                    <li class=showLb>[click to show LightBox]</li>
                    <li class=showLb>[click to show LightBox]</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I dont get it, so I would need to have two pieces of the same code?

Comment: I've tried but this works for som click events but  not for others

Comment: `showLb` is not a child of `results`, this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your on click method directly after you execute you ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
...
success: funtion(data){
       //your code
       $('.showLb').on('click',function(e){ alert('Show LightBox'); });
}
...
```

Comment: Don't do this. this is wrong. You should add attach the `on` to a static element not try and rebind in the success call back